# How to pass intent but not starting activity immediately

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to know if there is a way to pass an intent in Android with a string information from activity A to andother activity B that is part of a different app. The fact is I don't want B to start immediately, rather, when I later click on the launcher icon in the menu to start it, it should fecth the intent and update the UI. How to I got about doing that, if it is possible.

Comment: I tried using pendingIntent, but it immediately started app B...

Comment: How do you want to start activity B? Some callback function? Timer?

Comment: So why don't you create intent right before starting activity B? B isn't started from activity A?

Comment: B isn't started from A. Well i need to create the intent in A..how can I make sure that when I start B, that B see the intent i made in A?

Answer (score 1):

If you send the intent via startActivity, it will start the activity. If you rather just want to keep the info for the further launches :

The appropriate approach would be to use sharedpreferences.

- Save your data into sharedpreferences when you are in activity A
- When you launch the app again, check the preferences if there is any data, If there is data, simply get it and start activity B or take the action you like.

create a static factory method for the intent in Activity B, simply ActivityB will have the corresponding intent regardless of who calls it.

```
//ActivityB
public static Intent newIntent(Contex context){
    Intent intent = new Intent(contenxt, ActivityB.class); 

    // fill the intent from the shared preferences if there is any

    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Well actually, i want app A to create the intent for app B, but only when I decide to start app B, that is i manually want to start app B, should app B fetch to intent. I don't want to start App B from app A, I just want app A to provide then intent with the data, what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Maybe if I use pending intent in a way it would work? I trying to figure out how if it is possible..

Comment: you can fill the intent while creating the intent for the ActivityB, I updated my answer.